# Toggle AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code which loads content into a `div`, then fades in:

```
$('a.search').click(function(){
    $('.pop-up').load('search.php', function(){
        $(this).fadeToggle();
    });


});
```

However, I'm assuming this is making a request each time the `a.search` is clicked, if it is a toggle?

Is there a more economic way to achieve this toggle without making multiple calls?

Comment: A toggle how exactly ?

Comment: You want it to do a search and fade in the first time you click, then fade out the next time, without doing a search that time? Then do a search the next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the toggle in your own code instead of using `.fadeToggle`.

```
$('a.search').click(function(){
    if ($('.pop-up').is(':visible')) {
        $('.pop-up').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('.pop-up').load('search.php', function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for one time loading by setting a global variable.Assuming that your pop-up div style is set to `display:none`, example code is provided below:

```
var isPopUpLoaded = false;
$('a.search').click(function(){
    if(isPopUpLoaded==false){ 
       $('.pop-up').load('search.php', function(){
          isPopUpLoaded = true;
       });
   }
    $('.pop-up').fadeToggle();

})
```

;